# If integral of square of modulus of $f$ over $\mathbb C$ is finite, then $f \equiv 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Assume $f$ is entire and $\int \int |f(x+iy)|^2 dx dy < \infty$ , then show that $f \equiv 0$.

My approach was to notice that $|f|^2$ is a subharmonic function and then we can use the mean value inequality. Note that $$\int \int |f(x+iy)|^2  dxdy =  \int_0^{\infty} \int_{0} ^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2 rd\theta dr$$Now we know from subharmonicity $|f(0)|^2 \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(Re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta = \frac {1}{\pi R^2}\int_0^{R} \int_{0} ^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2 rd\theta dr$

As $R \rightarrow \infty$ , the rightmost term tends to  $0$ as we know $\int_0^{\infty} \int_{0} ^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2 rd\theta dr < \infty$, thus we have |f(0)| = 0. We could have chosen any $z$ in place of 0 and the argument would follow the same and thus we see $f \equiv 0$.

I was wondering if there is any way to get this result without the subharmonicity, I was trying to apply Liouville's but couldn't, if there is a simpler solution please let me know.

Comment: I've answered a similar question some time ago. Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096868/f-in-c2-mathbbr2-is-harmonic-f-is-in-one-lp-mathbbr2-impli/2102258#2102258

Comment: I believe your argument is the standard one. It is also possible to prove the result using distributions as I did on the post.

Comment: damn, sorry for reposting.